# Can I make one VR game in Unity that works with all PC VR sets (Oculus, HTC VIVE)

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am making a game for school with my friend, and we want to make it VR. Our school has no VR set but is willing to buy one for our project. We are also planning to upload our game onto Steam (I don't know if that changes anything).

I have seen how I can make a Unity game VR using VIVE and using Oculus, but I haven't seen any tutorials with both. So I was wondering if/how I can make it so that my game can use Oculus and VIVE, without having to make two different games for it.

I hope that by knowing this I can tell my school to buy the right VR set.

Comment: Not that I know of. But highly unlikely, the controls are completely different and you cannot use same control scripts for both devices.

Comment: As long as I have worked in VR, I would suggest to go for Oculus Rift/Oculus Rift S.

Comment: I'm currently working on this, and it's doable using the new input system and using generic XR controller. Give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible, the most common way would be to use SteamVR (aka OpenVR), it primarily targets Vive but works fine with Oculus (at least on the PC, I am not sure about Quest - its likely not supported).

Alternative is to to write your own wrappers to individual API's that would have implementation depending on the actual hardware platform. This should be possible to achieve wihtin a single ebinary but is a bit easier if you allow differen builds for each platform